# Coalesce vs. OR brings back different result set

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have two queries to get rows based on the EFFDT. One uses a coalesce on the two date conditions, the other an OR statement. The coalesce misses two people that the OR produces. Why?

I have been playing with the order of the coalesce arguments, if reversed, it misses one row (of a different employee) than the current order.

--The coalesce setup:

```
select *
from (select distinct JOB.EMPLID, JOB.EMPL_RCD, JOB.EFFDT
      from JOB JOB
     where JOB.EMPL_STATUS in ('A',
                               'P',
                               'L')
       and JOB.EFFDT =
           COALESCE((select min(JOB_ED2.EFFDT)
                      from PS_JOB JOB_ED2
                     where JOB_ED2.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID
                       and JOB_ED2.EMPL_RCD = JOB.EMPL_RCD
                       and JOB_ED2.EFFDT > '01-JUL-2018'),
                    (select max(JOB_ED.EFFDT)
                       from PS_JOB JOB_ED
                      where JOB_ED.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID
                        and JOB_ED.EMPL_RCD = JOB.EMPL_RCD
                        and JOB_ED.EFFDT <= '01-JUL-2018')) --two
       and JOB.EFFSEQ = (select max(JOB_ES.EFFSEQ)
                           from PS_JOB JOB_ES
                          where JOB_ES.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID
                            and JOB_ES.EMPL_RCD = JOB.EMPL_RCD
                            and JOB_ES.EFFDT = JOB.EFFDT)
```

The OR:

```
 (select distinct JOB.EMPLID as EMP2_ID, JOB.EMPL_RCD

from PS_JOB JOB
where JOB.EMPL_STATUS in ('A',
                         'L',
                         'P')
 and (JOB.EFFDT = (select max(JOB_ED.EFFDT)
                     from PS_JOB JOB_ED
                    where JOB_ED.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID
                      and JOB_ED.EMPL_RCD = JOB.EMPL_RCD
                      and JOB_ED.EFFDT <= '01-JUL-2018') or
     (JOB.EFFDT > '01-JUL-2018'))
 and JOB.EFFSEQ = (select max(JOB_ES.EFFSEQ)
                     from PS_JOB JOB_ES
                    where JOB_ES.EMPLID = JOB.EMPLID
                      and JOB_ES.EMPL_RCD = JOB.EMPL_RCD
                      and JOB_ES.EFFDT = JOB.EFFDT))
```

I expect the coalesce to bring back the same set as the OR just with the correct dates but it is missing these rows and I am just wondering why it isn't picking these up. I may have closed the brackets as these are code snippets so please spare the syntactical analysis if possible.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expression in ON and WHERE clauses.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way I could rewrite the min() portion of the coalesce to bring back the single row greater than the date without using the min function?

Answer (score 0):

In your *OR* version, you accept any JOB.EFFDT > '01-JUL-2018'.

In your *COALESCE* version, where JOB.EFFDT > '01-JUL-2018' you only accept JOB.EFFDT = min(JOB_ED2.EFFDT).

To be clear, if the two parameters of COALESCE are different from the two terms combined with OR, it's not surprising if the results are different.

COALESCE prioritises the results from left to right (so this is why reversing the arguments gives a different result), OR has no priority.

Comment: Yes. If I don't use the min() function I get the 'single-row subquery returns too many rows' error. The min() should return the minimum effective date greater than the date, correct?

Comment: Yes. I was pointing out a logical reason why the results of the two requests are different.
Your question doesn't have enough information to understand which is the best way to get the result you want. I suspect it's neither one of the above ! I think you would be better off with a JOIN.

Comment: I don't want to know the "best way", I already understand the bottom query is going to produce a complete result set. What I want to know is how I get the coalesce to produce the same results as the OR. There is surely enough code to understand what I am trying to accomplish. And a join has nothing to do with this code or my objective. These are bad answers to my query.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. If the OR gives the result you want, why do you want to use COALESCE?

Comment: With COALESCE I could grab single row data as the COALESCE would return only a single value, where the OR creates multiple rows. It is merely an academic pursuit in trying to understand why the COALESCE misses a row that the OR returns, and what I can change in the coalesce to produce the same results as the OR.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. I apologize for the lack of greater context. However it seems that the effseq portion of the COALESCE needed to be included in the subqueries, not used externally. I appreciate the assistance, and our commentary helped shape how I got the answer.